# Can no longer send a photo from camera roll to a shared album

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

iPhone SE, iOS 14.5.1

For years I have made a new Shared Library every year with the year in the title, to share with my other half.  This has always worked, and she has a shared library of photos I have sent her for each of the last 7-8 years or so.  But I recently upgraded my OS (always a scary proposition with Apple) and I can no longer share photos from the camera roll, to a shared album!  The option simply doesn't appear.  I can email them, send them via Messages, AirDrop, Dropbox, Google Drive, and a ton of other things.  But there is no option anywhere that I can see, to add the selected photos to a shared album.

Album Sharing is enabled, iCloud is working, etc.

How can I add a photo to a shared album in iOS 14.5.1?

Comment: Wow... NOBODY knows how to do this, not even with a bounty attached?  I'm rather stunned.

Answer (score 0):

Open settings, tap your name, tap iCloud, tap Photos and make sure "Shared albums" are turned on. If it already are on, restart the Photos app (double tap home button and swipe up the Photos app in the app switcher) and look for the "Add to shared album" option you found missing earlier. If the option is still missing try to turn the "Shared album" option off in settings, reboot you iPhone then turn it on again then reboot it once more.

Make sure that the file type of the photo is supported. According to Apple, following formats are supported in Shared Albums:
Images:

- HEIF
- JPEG
- RAW*
- PNG
- GIF
- TIFF

*Not supported on Windows.

Videos:

- HEVC
- MP4
- QuickTime
- H.264
- MPEG-4

The way you try to add photos to a shared album is the correct way, according to Apple support article. You can also add photos to a shared album by open the album and tap the "+" sign after the last photo in the album.

Ref: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786

*Tried with iOS 14.7.1 on an iPhone. Update to this version of iOS if issue still persist.*

Comment: Nope, no such option.  I had done this numerous times as well in the past, no go.  I am updated to 14.7.1 now also btw.

Comment: @jvc If you open one of the shared albums you already have in photos app. What appears after the last image?

Comment: I can add any photos as you would expect.  But this is a very sub-optimal way to do it as I basically never ever use the Photos app.  I take a photo, and share it to the folder, done.  I just want to be able to do this from the camera itself just like I have always been able to before iOS 14.

Comment: @jvc Where in the camera app do you expect the share option to appear? Please be precise.

Comment: The same place it has always been.  I could view any photo I had in my camera role, and simply share it to a photo album.  This has been the case for many years, and that feature now seems to be gone.

Comment: it works in iOS/iPadOS 14.7.1.